# Managed paths in SharePoint Online?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online

With SharePoint Online Admin Portal being so limited I'm quite confident that there's no way within it to setup wildcards and managed paths.

Is this now available through PowerShell or now a redundant (hopefully roadmapped) feature?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is still not an option in Office 365

Comment: @RobertLindgren That's a shame... huge barrier for a lot of deployments then. Going to have to talk clients away from o365 :(